# pseudo-mask about Weakly Supervised Semantic Segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, artificial-intelligence, multilabel

I am following the process described in that image --->[image]to generate my high-quality pseudo-mask for the task of semantic segmentation. However, after training a classification model to obtain the CAM (Class Activation Map), I notice that the CAM is of undesired quality(Why are there overlaps of different classes in the same area, some non-existent class, but also appears in the CAM of its corresponding class?...). How can I generate a high-quality CAM?

Comment: Please do not simply repost [closed questions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/642882/1352). Instead, edit them to address the reason for closure, which will put the edited post into a queue to be voted for reopening.